# SQL to return a table based on string input

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am a new with T-SQL. So, please help me to write the sql.

I have table Price (Code column is primary column):

```
Code    Value
A1       234
A2       525 
A3       566
```

I will input a string and the sql need to return a table.

Ex1: input 'A2' -> return:

```
Code    Value
A2       525
```

Ex2: input 'A1 A3' -> return:

```
Code    Value
A1       234
A3       566
```

Ex3: input 'A1 A3 A1' -> return:

```
Code    Value
A1       234
A3       566
```

Ex4: input 'A1 A4' -> return:

```
Code    Value
A1       234
```

Please help me. I am using SQL Server 2005. Tks.

Comment: question do you want separate statements for each or one stored procedure that will allow you to return all these scenarios?

Comment: I need to write a stored procedure which requires a string parameter and output a table. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [Price].Code, [Price].Value FROM [Price] WHERE [Price].Code IN ('A1', 'A2');
```

It's very effective, but it has two limitations:

- You can't use regular SQL parameters in an `IN` clause, so you'll have append it to your SQL string automatically, which, in some cases, could open SQL Injections.
- It's not exactly the input format you requsted: instead of `A2 A2` it's `'A1', 'A2'`.

Good luck anyway!

**EDIT:** If you really want to use the `A1 A2` format, you can't use `IN` and you'd have to split the string and then check if it contains the current `[Price].Code`. Just note that it will be much less effective than my first example.

T-SQL doesn't support `Split` by default, so you'll have to add it manually:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(    
    @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimeter NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Data NVARCHAR(MAX)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Iterator INT
    SET @Iterator = 1

    DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@RowData)

    WHILE (@FoundIndex>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data)
        SELECT 
            Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)))

        SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,
                @FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@Delimeter) / 2,
                LEN(@RowData))

        SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @RowData)
    END

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Data)
    SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))

    RETURN
END
```

And then, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT [Price].Code, [Price].Value FROM [Price] 
JOIN Split(@Codes, ' ') AS [Code] 
 ON [Code].Data = [Price].Code
```

[Here's the source for the Split function](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx).

Comment: But how to split string from 'A1 A2' to 'A1' and 'A2'. My store procedure requires a string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As Alon mentioned, you need a function or query to split the values into rows in a table. Another way to do this is with a Numbers table which can be static or created as part of a common table expression:

```
Declare @Alist varchar(50);
Declare @Delimiter char(1);
Declare @DelimiterLength int;

Set @Delimiter = ' ';
Set @DelimiterLength = DataLength(@Delimiter);
Set @Alist = 'A1 A2 A3';
Set @Alist = @Delimiter + @Alist + @Delimiter;

With Numbers As
    (
    Select Row_Number() Over ( Order By C1.object_id ) As Value
    From sys.columns As C1
        Cross Join sys.columns As C2
    )
Select CharIndex(@Delimiter, @Alist, N.Value) + @DelimiterLength As Position            
    , Substring (
                @Alist
                , CharIndex(@Delimiter, @Alist, N.Value) + @DelimiterLength         
                , CharIndex(@Delimiter, @Alist, N.Value + 1)                            
                    - ( CharIndex(@Delimiter, @Alist, N.Value) + @DelimiterLength ) 
                ) As Value
From Numbers As N
Where N.Value Between 1 And ( Len(@Alist) - 1 )
    And Substring(@Alist, N.Value, @DelimiterLength) = @Delimiter
Order By N.Value
```

Here the space delimiter presents a small problem. The `Len` function ignores spaces in its determination so I used the `DataLength` function and also ensure that `@Delimiter` was declared as a `varchar` instead of a `nvarchar`. `DataLength` will return the number of bytes in the string which will be twice the number of characters in general for a `nvarchar`.

The Numbers CTE (or it could be a static table) is just a static list of sequential integers which is quite useful for situations just like this one.

This type of approach can also be incorporated into a general query where you analyze every row in another table like so:

```
With Numbers As
    (
    Select Row_Number() Over ( Order By C1.object_id ) As Value
    From sys.columns As C1
        Cross Join sys.columns As C2
    )
Select CharIndex(@Delimiter, A.List, N.Value) + @DelimiterLength            
    , Substring (
                A.List
                , CharIndex(@Delimiter, A.List, N.Value) + @DelimiterLength         
                , CharIndex(@Delimiter, A.List, N.Value + 1)                            
                    - ( CharIndex(@Delimiter, A.List, N.Value) + @DelimiterLength ) 
                )
From Numbers As N
    Cross Join ( Select A1.List From SomeTable ) As A
Where N.Value Between 1 And ( Len(A.List) - 1 )
    And Substring(A.List, N.Value, @DelimiterLength) = @Delimiter
Order By N.Value
```